# handling multiple chat boxes in ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

i am planning to implement chat application using ajax, java script in front and java rest api in back . everything is going  well, but whenever i try to open multiple chat boxes  to chat with multiple user. i am struggling to create different chat boxes associated with different users. my entire front-end code is below . Can somebody please help me? thanks in advance...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Chat Application</title>
    <style>
        .userListDiv{
            border:1px solid blue;
            overflow: auto;
            width:500px;

        }
        #messageBox{
            border:2px solid black;
            overflow: auto;
            height:auto;
            width:300px;
        }
        #messageInput{
         size:100px;
            border:1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway'
    rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.sidr/2.2.1/stylesheets/jquery.sidr.light.min.css">

    </head>

    <body>
        <button id='myId' value =userId></button>

        <div class="userListDiv"></div>
        <div class ="chatbox">
        <div id ="messageBox">
            </div>
        </div>




<script>
 var baseUrl="http://localhost:8080/sampleHospital/webapi/";

$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#myId').hide();
 $('.chatbox').hide();


    var timeOut = 1000;

    $.ajax({
        url: baseUrl+"users",
        method:"GET",
        datatype:"xml",
        success:getUsers,
        error: function(xhr,ajaxOption,thrownError){
           console.log(xhr.status);
           console.log(thrownError); 
        }


    }, timeOut);

        });


function sendMessage(senderId,recieverId){
   var Inputmessage= $('.messageInput').val();
    var message = $.parseXML('<message><date></date><id></id><senderID></senderID><recieverID></recieverID><content></content></message>');
    var $messageXml = $(message);
    $messageXml.find('content').append(Inputmessage);
    $messageXml.find('senderID').append(senderId);
    $messageXml.find('recieverID').append(recieverId);

    console.log(message);
    $('.messageInput').val="";
    $.ajax({
        url: baseUrl+"messages/",
        type:"POST",
        dataType:'xml',
        data:message,
        processData:false,
        contentType:"application/xml",
        success: getMessage,


        error: function(xhr){
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log("error!!!");
        }


    });

}
function requestMessage(senderID, recieverID){
            var timeInterval = 1000;

        $(".chatbox").fadeIn(500);
        $(".chatbox").append("<div id ='chatContainer'></div>");
        $('.chatbox').append('<input type="text" class="messageInput" placeHolder="your message here"/><button class="sendMessage" onclick="sendMessage(1,2)">send message</button>');
        $.ajax({
            url:baseUrl +"messages/"+senderID +"/"+ recieverID,
            method:"GET",
            datatype:"xml",
            success :getMessage,
            error: function(xhr ,ajaxOptions,thrownError){
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(thrownError);
        }

        }, timeInterval);

        }
function getMessage(data,status){
    console.log("getting messages");
    console.log(data);
     var messageBox =$("#messageBox") ;
     messageBox.empty();
     messageBox.append($('<ul id ="messagesList"></ul>'));
        $(data).find('message').each(function(){
            var message = $(this).find('content').text();
            var date = $(this).find('date').text();
            var sender = $(this).find('senderID').text();
            var receiver = $(this).find('recieverID').text();
            console.log(message);

     $("#messagesList").append('<li>'+message+'</li>');
        });

}
      function getUsers(data,status){
         console.log("getting users list");
         console.log(data);
         var userListBox = $(".userListDiv");
         userListBox.empty();
          userListBox.append('<ul class="usersList"></ul>');
         $(data).find('user').each(function(){
             var name = $(this).find('fullName').text();
         var otherid =   $(this).find('id').text();


           var myId =2;

          // console.log(name,otherid);



             $('.usersList').append('<li class='+name+' onclick="requestMessage(1,2)"><a href="javaScript:void(0)">'+name+'</li>');
     });
      }
</script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

in the request message you are trying to create chatcontainer div. For any user you are using same div id so you wont be able to update the values properly. You should create the id uniquely may be appending with receiver id. More over if div with that id is there then you should not create it again. you should use the existing div and update the messages.